# An Exercise from Manetti's Topologia

Tags: general-topology

I Have to show that that the quotient space $R^2/D^2$ is homeomorphic to $R^2$. My idea is to find a continuous function
$$
f: R^2 \mapsto R^2
$$
such that $f(D^2)=O$, where $O=(0,0)$.
Nevertheless, I can't find this function. Can you help me?

Comment: HINT: For $p\in\Bbb R^2$ consider the distance from $p$ to $D$.

Comment: If I take the distance, I shall obtain a function $f: R^2 \mapsto \R$ and not to $R^2$.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wasn’t suggesting it for $f$. It is, however, relevant to the simplest way to define $f$, which I see has now been given in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ as

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }\; \|x\|\le1  \\
\big(\frac{\|x\|-1}{\|x\|}\big)x & \text{if }\; \|x\|>1
\end{cases}
$$